# Free sound library, catalog or search engine

Tags: untagged

I'm in the process of organizing my entire library.

What I'd really like now is a way to search the library rather than MacOSx search or PT search.  I'm naming my files like. bird.whipporwill.call  with periods to try and help the search engine.

Is there a free one out there that I can pick up? Does anybody know how to alter the preferences of the MacOSx finder search or PT9's search?

Comment: Hmm. In Pro Tools 7 I can make a catalogue of any hard-drive so it has a database of each file and can search faster. Have you tried that?

Comment: Why free? Considering all your investment in time, energy & other hardware why not support one of the developers who spend many many hours/days/weeks/years of their time? It seems a small price to pay

Comment: Cos I'm broke.  Yeah.  Id LOVE to buy soundminer and I don't know what I'd get first, that or a graphical time/pitch shifter.

Comment: @Utopia.  Can you do that with PT9?  (which I just upgraded to and am pretty happy about the updated track count to say the least).

Comment: @Utopia Is it a definite noticeable difference making a catalog, or just a small difference in search speed?

Answer (score 2):

Ah man, I just came across a cool one the other day.

*franticly tick taps google*

*fails and asks fellow sound designer Francis Hooper (friggin' amazing btw)*

Basehead. Its like 300 bucks as opposed to the 600-900 soundminder search. In terms of differences Im not up to date on them.

Some other ones include:

media monkey

library monkey

wtf is up with monkey monkey

Iced Audio

NetMix

Shew, I know there is a few more out there.

Answer (score 1):

Try iTunes also

Answer (score 0):

Right now I'm just using the Finder. I'm working in somebody else's studio without Soundminer, so I brought my library disk in order to speed up things a little bit. So I'm searching my sound archive folder while in preview mode (press space in finder while focused on a file), and dragging and dropping directly into Protools on the track. At least this works super fine with stereo files - a bit risky though with mono files - if they are 48k 24 bit mono WAV, they are simply added to my session instead of being copied to my session folder, which is a no go!

So if the files turn out to be mono, I import them using the Protools import menu, and copy them to the session.

Of course I can't spot inside files or just import parts of a soundfile, but it works pretty well for a free solution.

Comment: @Morten In regards to dragging mono files into your PT session, do you have "Automatically Copy Files on Import" selected in your PT preferences?  This should make a copy of all dragged files in your session folder, unless it's a bug of some sort, specific to 48k, 24 bit mono files.

Comment: Well, every once in a while you learn something new! Thanks! This is like the experience I had a year ago, with over 10 years of Protools experience, when somebody told me about cmd-T....

Answer (score 0):

I use Easyfind from [Devon technologies](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/freeware/). Again, it doesn't support audio-specific functions, but works very well if your filenames contain keywords. OS X Quick Look is built in for easy auditioning, and it can search across network volumes that may not be indexed by Spotlight.